# Visual Studio Code launches Firefox using an empty profile on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, archlinux

I installed Visual Studio Code Insiders on Arch Linux using Snap.  I have Firefox configured as my default browser in KDE.  Whenever VSCode launches Firefox, it does so using an empty profile instead of the default profile that contains all my installed extensions, including my password manager.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with being installed via Snap since when I install it on Kubuntu using the ".deb" package, it launches Firefox normally with all my extensions loaded.

Is this a bug, or is there some kind of configuration change I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Open some URL from the VSCode snap.

In the new window, navigate to about:profiles.

Ensure that the profile marked as "Default Profile" matches Firefox when opened normally.

Use the "Set as default profile" button under the correct profile to change the default.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96829#issuecomment-695391809